# Katakana character ジ in URL being encoded incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, urlencode

I need to construct a URL with a string path received from my application server which contains the character: `ジ`

However, in Swift, the `fileURLWithPath` seems to encode it incorrectly.

```swift
let path = "ジ"
print(URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
print(URL(fileURLWithPath: path.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping))
```

Both print:

```
%E3%82%B7%E3%82%99
```

This expected URL path should be:

```
%E3%82%B8
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `fileURLWithPath` expects a file system path which must start with a `/`

Comment: Hi @vadian, yes. I do have a path that starts with a '/'. I just pasted the offending portion of the path which is the katakana character with diacritic.

Comment: Some explanation [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/30b8/index.htm) : this a decomposition of the character

Comment: Is this in fact a file URL? Please give real code and real circumstances. Otherwise it's very hard to help; we just have to guess what you mean, which is no fun.

Comment: `init(fileURLWithPath:)` is for constructing **local** URLs. From the docs: "Creates a file URL that references the local file or directory at path." It is not appropriate for URLs you send to a server for its own use; the server cannot access your local filesystem. Can you explain what you're doing with URL? You mention both that it comes from the server, and that you're sending it back to the server. I'm having trouble picturing exactly how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different characters, `ジ` and `ジ`. They may look the same, but they have different internal representations.

- The former is “katakana letter zi”, comprised of a single Unicode scalar which percent-encodes as `%E3%82%B8`.
- The latter is still a single Swift character, but is comprised of two Unicode scalars (the “katakana letter si” and “combining voiced sound mark”), and these two Unicode scalars percent-encode to `%E3%82%B7%E3%82%99`.

One can normalize characters in a string with [`precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412645-precomposedstringwithcanonicalma), for example. That can convert a character with the two Unicode scalars into a character with a single Unicode scalar.

But your local file system (or, `init(fileURLWithPath:)`, at least) decomposes diacritics. It is logical that the local file system ensures that diacritics are encoded in some consistent manner. (See [Diacritics in file names on macOS behave strangely](https://superuser.com/questions/1490652/diacritics-in-file-names-on-macos-behave-strangely).) The fact that they are decomposed rather than precomposed is, for the sake of this discussion, a bit academic. When you send it to the server, you want it precomposed, regardless of what is happening in your local file system.

Now, you tell us that the “url path is rejected by the server”. That does not make sense. One would generally not provide a local file system URL to a remote server. One would generally extract a file name from a local file system URL and send that to the server. This might be done in a variety of ways:

- You *can* use [`precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412645-precomposedstringwithcanonicalma) when adding a filename to a server URL, and it honors that mapping, unlike a file URL:

  ```swift
  let path = "ジ"      // actually `%E3%82%B7%E3%82%99` variant
  let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
      .appendingPathComponent(path.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping)
  print(url)          // https://example.com/%E3%82%B8
  ```
- If sending it in the body of a request, use `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`. E.g. if a `filename` in a `multipart/form-data` request:

  ```swift
  body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
  body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey)\"; filename=\"\(filename.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping)\"\r\n")
  body.append("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n")
  body.append(data)
  body.append("\r\n")
  ```

Now, those are two random examples of how a filename might be provided to the server. Yours may vary. But the idea is that when you provide the filename, that you precompose the string in its canonical format, rather than relying upon what a file URL in your local file system uses.

But I would advise avoiding `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` for manipulating strings provided by the server. It is only to be used when actually referring to files within your local file system. If you just want to percent-encode strings, I would advise using the `String` method `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)`. That will not override the `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` output.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this approach using `dataRepresentation`:

```
if let path = "ジ".data(using: .utf8),
   let url = URL(dataRepresentation: path, relativeTo: nil) {
    print("\n---> url: \(url) \n") //---> url: %E3%82%B8
}
```

Comment: converting any string to utf8 data representation will never fail `Data("ジ".utf8)`